# JavaScript keeps breaking

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I am trying to make a website and the It has a page that asks questions and depending on the radio buttons selected it will give you one of two answers. If a "yes" is selected it will tell you that you failed. If you select all five as "no" it will tell you that you passed. I had this working when I only had three questions but when I tried to add two more for a total of five and changed the code to match it stopped working. It won't give me an answer no matter what choices I have selected.

This is the HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
    <fieldset>
        <h3>
            <legend>Eligibility Test</legend>
        </h3>
    </fieldset>

    <p>Please Answer the following questions to determine if you are eligible for expungement.</p>

    <fieldset>

        <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
        <input id="exp_yes" type="radio" name="field1" value="0" />
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
        <input id="exp_no" type="radio" name="field1" value="1" />
        <label>
            No
        </label>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
        <input id="chg_yes" type="radio" name="field2" value="0" />
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
        <input id="chg_no" type="radio" name="field2" value="1" />
        <label>
            No
        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Have any of your convictions ever been for a murder / manslaughter or attempt of the same?</legend>
        <input id="mur_yes" type="radio" name="field3" value="0" />
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
        <input id="mur_no" type="radio" name="field3" value="1" />
        <label>
            No
        </label>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Have any of your convictions been for a sex crime or required you to sign up for the sex offender registry?</legend>
        <input id="off_yes" type="radio" name="field4" value="0" />
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
        <input id="off_no" type="radio" name="field4" value="1" />
        <label>
            No
        </label>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Do you still owe any fines, fees, or restitution on any of criminal convictions?
        </legend>
        <input id="fin_yes" type="radio" name="field5" value="0" />
        <label>
            Yes
        </label>
        <input id="fin_no" type="radio" name="field5" value="1" />
        <label>
            No
        </label>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="submitbutton">
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer()' />
    </fieldset>
    <div id="first">
        <p id="totalScore"></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
function answer(total) {
    var score = 0;
    if (document.getElementById('exp_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('chg_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('mur_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('off_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('fin_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (score != 5) {
        document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You may not yet be 
        fully eligible to get your record expunged.Though this test should not be
        considered as a definite answer.Please call 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our
        contact page to schedule a meeting
        for a proper assessment.
        ";
        toggletab();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You appear to be eligible 
        for expungment!Please contact 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our contact page to
        schedule a meeting and to talk to about your next steps!";
        toggletab2();
    }
}

function answer(total) {
    var score = 0;
    if (document.getElementById('exp_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('chg_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('mur_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('off_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('fin_no').checked) {
        score++;
    }
    if (score != 5) {
        document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You may not yet be 
        fully eligible to get your record expunged.Though this test should not be
        considered as a definite answer.Please call 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our
        contact page to schedule a meeting
        for a proper assessment.
        ";
        toggletab();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You appear to be eligible 
        for expungment!Please contact 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our contact page to
        schedule a meeting and to talk to about your next steps!";
        toggletab2();
    }
}
```

Thank you, I really don't understand why it keeps breaking when I try to adjust it.

Comment: what so you mean by "breaking"? Could you paste the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be with your `.innerHTML` text strings. Due to your formatting, JavaScript is interpreting your first text string as `You may not yet be`, and then throwing a syntax error thinking `fully eligible` is invalid JavaScript.

Storing the entire string on a single line appears to resolve the problem:

```js
function answer(total) {
  var score = 0;
  if (document.getElementById('exp_no').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('chg_no').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('mur_no').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('off_no').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('fin_no').checked) {
    score++;
  }
  if (score != 5) {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You may not yet be fully eligible to get your record expunged. Though this test should not be considered as a definite answer. Please call 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our contact page to schedule a meeting for a proper assessment.";
    //toggletab();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You appear to be eligible for expungment! Please contact 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our contact page to schedule a meeting and to talk to about your next steps!";
    //toggletab2();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <h3>
      <legend>Eligibility Test</legend>
    </h3>
  </fieldset>
  <p>Please Answer the following questions to determine if you are eligible for expungement.</p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
    <input id="exp_yes" type="radio" name="field1" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="exp_no" type="radio" name="field1" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
    <input id="chg_yes" type="radio" name="field2" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="chg_no" type="radio" name="field2" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have any of your convictions ever been for a murder / manslaughter or attempt of the same?</legend>
    <input id="mur_yes" type="radio" name="field3" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="mur_no" type="radio" name="field3" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have any of your convictions been for a sex crime or required you to sign up for the sex offender registry?</legend>
    <input id="off_yes" type="radio" name="field4" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="off_no" type="radio" name="field4" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Do you still owe any fines, fees, or restitution on any of criminal convictions?
    </legend>
    <input id="fin_yes" type="radio" name="field5" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="fin_no" type="radio" name="field5" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="submitbutton">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer()' />
  </fieldset>
  <div id="first">
    <p id="totalScore"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that I've commented out `toggletab()` and `toggletab2()`, as those two functions are undefined in your example.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Just to elaborate, javascript interprets the end of line as the end of command, the equivalent of `;`. Even within a string. Use `\r\n` to mark a new line (carriage Return , New line if we're being specific) within a string for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

For fun and games I'm going to take [Obsidians answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47745639/4665) and refine it a little.

Obsidian has nailed your issue though (so out of our two answers, they deserve the accepted answer honor). Strings need to be on one line. Javascript will treat any new line, even within string delimiters as a new command.

Using the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method we can compare the lenght of elements found using CSS selectors.

```js
function answer(total) {
  var score = 0;
  
  //This all seemed like a good idea at the time but there is a better way!
  //Get all our no buttons -> Any radio button with a value of one that is in a fieldset tag.
  //var noButtons = document.querySelectorAll("fieldset input[type='radio'][value='1']");
  
  //Loop through our no buttons keeping a track of the score
  /*for(var i = 0; i < noButtons.length; i++){
    if(noButtons[i].checked){
      score++;
    }
  }*/
  
 
  //If there are un checked no buttons....uh oh!
  //if (score != noButtons.length) {
  
  //The if statme below does the following
  //Find all radio buttons with a value of 1 that are checked and are in a field set and count them.
  //Compare that to the number of radio buttons with a value of radio buttons with a value of 1 that are in a field set.
  if(document.querySelectorAll("fieldset input[type='radio'][value='1']:checked").length != document.querySelectorAll("fieldset input[type='radio'][value='1']").length) {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You may not yet be fully eligible to get your record expunged. Though this test should not be considered as a definite answer. Please call 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our contact page to schedule a meeting for a proper assessment.";
    //toggletab();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('totalScore').innerHTML = "You appear to be eligible for expungment! Please contact 574 - 931 - 2173 or visit our contact page to schedule a meeting and to talk to about your next steps!";
    //toggletab2();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <h3>
      <legend>Eligibility Test</legend>
    </h3>
  </fieldset>
  <p>Please Answer the following questions to determine if you are eligible for expungement.</p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have you had your record expunged before?</legend>
    <input id="exp_yes" type="radio" name="field1" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="exp_no" type="radio" name="field1" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Do you have any charges pending against you?</legend>
    <input id="chg_yes" type="radio" name="field2" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="chg_no" type="radio" name="field2" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have any of your convictions ever been for a murder / manslaughter or attempt of the same?</legend>
    <input id="mur_yes" type="radio" name="field3" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="mur_no" type="radio" name="field3" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Have any of your convictions been for a sex crime or required you to sign up for the sex offender registry?</legend>
    <input id="off_yes" type="radio" name="field4" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="off_no" type="radio" name="field4" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Do you still owe any fines, fees, or restitution on any of criminal convictions?
    </legend>
    <input id="fin_yes" type="radio" name="field5" value="0" />
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input id="fin_no" type="radio" name="field5" value="1" />
    <label>No</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="submitbutton">
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick='answer()' />
  </fieldset>
  <div id="first">
    <p id="totalScore"></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Basically what I've done here is made your life easier if you want to add or remove questions. You don't have to go and recode. You could also you css classes or data attributes to define your no buttons.